# Angular - Parameter for SQL

Tags: angularjs

I have followed the basics from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp

I now have controller with this line:

```
$http.get("getjson.php?q=2") 
(let's say it's making a json based on select * from someplace where country=2)
```

How can I get this dynamic so that I can use the same angular module for all the x countries I want to list? I guess copying the module x times and hard code the country number isn't the best option...

Answer (score 0):

You can crate service that implements your get request

```
angular.service('someService', function() {
  this.getJson = function(qParam){
    $http.getjson('getjson.php',{q:qParam});
  }
})
```

you can use it in controller like this

```
angular.controller('mainController',function(someService){
  someService.getjson(2);
})
```